# Messaging icon in Samsung S3 always show one unread message

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms

My Samsung S3 messaging icon always show one unread message. See the screenshot below. I have thoroughly checked if there are any unread messages and also restarted the phone couple of times. I also removed the battery for sometime. Any clue as to what might be causing it?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: did u try removing the icon and add again?

Comment: The problem resolved after the last software update.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings > Application Manager > All applications (on the top)`. Locate the "BadgeProvider" app and select "clear data". After that, restart the phone.

Comment: While this is a temporary solution, I'd like to see a more permanent one, as I have the same issue. I can of course see that this would possibly be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that a message on your SIM card? You should be able to access SIM card messages to see it and/or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to remove it, you need to **send yourself a message** from **another phone** and **read the text message**, then the **"1" will disappear**.

This also works for `Whatsapp` etc.

Hope my answer helps.